# How to resize the window depending on the region that the canvas items occupy?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, window

I have a program that when initialised it draws its content in a canvas that occupies the hole window.
What i would want to do is to resize the window's dimentions so the window fits the canvas objects scrollregion.

Comment: Are you asking how to resize a window to a fixed size? This is well documented and has problem been asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know tkinter adjusts and resizes the window automatically in order to display all given elements. So all you have to do is leave all size information for the window (not the elements you add to the canvas) away or set them way too small (eg. height=10, width=10).
Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't resize based on items drawn on a canvas, which is what this question is asking.

Comment: Exacly, with items drawn in canvas it wont resize

Comment: Okey its as simple as setting the geometry of the window at the end, sorry for the question and thank you!